# ETIMEDOUT for downloading image using AXIOS in node.js npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, axios, imagedownload

`code: 'ETIMEDOUT', host: 'miro.medium.com', hostname: 'miro.medium.com', method: 'GET', path: '/v2/resize:fit:1200/1*zPt6so-N8gphr7Kyw6OA1w.jpeg', protocol: 'https:', url: 'https://miro.medium.com/v2/resize:fit:1200/1*zPt6so-N8gphr7Kyw6OA1w.jpeg'`

Getting this error while downloading image using AXIOS npm package in node.js.

The code used is provided below:

```
let inputImageUrl = "https://miro.medium.com/v2/resize:fit:1200/1%2AzPt6so-N8gphr7Kyw6OA1w.jpeg";

// Decode the URL to remove percent-encoded characters
          const decodedUrl = decodeURIComponent(inputImageUrl);

          // Set a User-Agent header to mimic a browser request
          const userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.0.0 Safari/537.36";

          axios
            .get(decodedUrl, {
              headers: {
                "User-Agent": userAgent
              },
              responseType: "stream",
              timeout: 10000 // Increase the timeout to 10 seconds (adjust as needed)
            })
            .then((response) => {
              // Handle the response
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              console.error(err);
            });
```

I have decoded the input image url and used the decoded url to download but still issue occured, the error is added above.

The correct url is as follows "https://miro.medium.com/v2/resize:fit:1200/1%2AzPt6so-N8gphr7Kyw6OA1w.jpeg"

I have also tried SuperAgent, download, node-downloader-helper packages to download this image, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem with the code; you can ensure that with another image URL.

It seems **Miro** has limited external access to the assets.